Classification with (Latent) Neural Process
in a latent Neural Process, we make a prediction using the latent vector $z$ and the inputs $x_i$. In the regression problem, one predicts a $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$ that define a Normal distribution, given $x_i$ and $z$.
So how does it work for a Classification, how would I define the final predicted distribution?
I am specifically not talking about the Normal Distributions of the latent space. From which $z$ is drawn.
A pytorch code example:
z_sample = q_target.rsample()

# Get parameters of output distribution
y_pred_mu, y_pred_sigma = self.xz_to_y(x_target, z_sample)
p_y_pred = Normal(y_pred_mu, y_pred_sigma)

Here p_y_pred is predicted Normal distribution for $y_i$
